# Bootstrap site is not load when use laravel form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I have a bootstrap template for my website. I have successfully convert it into Laravel 5.

The problem is, when I code Laravel form in blade files, that site is not loading, if there is no Laravel code it loads successfully.

Here's the form code.

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'/edit_contact')) !!}

    {!! Form::text('email_edit', null, [
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'style' => 'color:#000000; background-color:#ffffff; border-width:1px; border-color:#41A6FF',
        'placeholder'=>'Enter Your E-mail Here'
    ]) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Submit To Edit', [
        'type'  => 'button',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        'style' => 'color:#000000; background-color:#ffffff; color:#000000'
    ]) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Can we see this code? Did you correctly name your blade views? (`filename.blade.php`)

Comment: yes i named it correctly. it was successfully load when there are no laavel codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html` package was deprecated from Laravel 5 and you should install a third party package for Html and Form.

The most popular package and alternative for Laravel Html package is `laravelcollective/html`

You can install in easily by composer:

```
composer install laravelcollective/html
```

For more information visit [this](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html).

Answer (score 0):

check HTMLForm in your comopser file check [Laravel Forms](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/10)